# How would I use a SQL query in the MVC controller, and get the value to show in a PDF

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

The problem I'm having is that I'm not being able to retrieve the value of the query the same way I get when I use the same query in the SQL Server Management Studio.

I tried using sqlQuery in the MVC but I was getting the whole string instead of the value of that query.

SQL query in Studio

```
SELECT convert(varchar(8), dateadd(second, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, [----------], [----------])), 0),  108) as Total
from ---------- where ---------- = '1'
```

Controller Query

```
var query = db.Work.SqlQuery("SELECT convert(varchar(8), dateadd(second, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, [----------], [----------])), 0),  108) as Total from ---------- where ----------= '1'");
```

Then where I want it to show

```
graphics.DrawTextBox(MarginLeftTextBox + 120f * 4, MarginTop + lineStepDown + 330f, 240.0f, regularTextStyle.FontSize + 2f, >>HERE<<, regularTextStyle2, TextAlignment.Center, thinBorder);
```

When I type query.toString() where >>HERE<< is, it just shows the whole query instead of the value of the query that should be 19:30:00.

Comment: Execute the query and put the result >>HERE<<

Comment: What you've got there is a just a string variable, which contains a SQL query. You need to **execute** the query and retrieve the result into a new variable. Figure that part out before you worry about anything to do with PDFs.

Comment: I would expect `query` to be an `IQueryable` or at least an `IEnumerable` of some sort.  Where do you try to use it afterward?

Comment: You tried adding on a .FirstOrDefault(); to the sqlQuery line to execute it?

Comment: Yes I tried using .FirstOrDefault(), it says 
Error CS1503 Argument 5: cannot convert from 'CPATV1.Models.Work' to 'string', then I added .toString() and the whole region disappears, with executing you guys mean using .FirstOrDefault() right?

Comment: Well, the way you have it now, I think the `SqlQuery()` command should be executing your query, and `query` should (if it succeeds) contain some sort of result. What type of object does the `SqlQuery()` run? i.e. What is the dataType of `query`? You just defined it as var, but its real type is, as David said, likely to be `IEnumerable` or something like that (i.e. a list of results). Can you check and verify that for us please? That will help us to understand how you should use that result.

Comment: @ADyson when I write query. it shows the collumns I have in the database.

Comment: No, that's not what I asked. Do you understand what I mean by the "data type" of your variable?

Comment: @ADyson Yes, if its a integer, float, etc,  it should be a nvarchar, but I got no access, when I tried to convert it the first few times I tried this it showed cannot convert nvarchar to datetime, but I got that fixed now, I tried running the code now and put a breakpoint on the query and it breaks there.

Comment: That's a complicated answer to a simple question. You said "it should be a nvarchar". But a) I'm not interested in "should", I want to know what type it actually **is** in reality. And b) nvarchar is a SQL data type. I'm talking about the .NET datatype. So again, what is the datatype of `query`?

Comment: "put a breakpoint on the query and it breaks there" ....so what? If you put a breakpoint then of course it will break there. That's not an interesting piece of information. What might be interesting is what, if anything, you discover when you do that.

Comment: I put the break-point at the beginning and it runs everything before that, I dont understand what do you mean by the datatype of the query, if it's not var, it's either Work, which is my table name or Void @ADyson After hovering the variable it says Work query, sorry.

Comment: "if it's not var" ...var is just a shorthand to stop you having to write the full datatype in the code every time. It's not a real datatype. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var.  The var will become whatever data type is returned by the `SqlQuery()` method. Your Visual Studio Intellisense (or the relevant documentation) can tell you what that type is.

Comment: "it runs everything before that" ...and what happens if you don't set the breakpoint? Does it crash?

Comment: @ADyson It crashes that specific region yes. Everything else works.

Comment: Right. And what's the exact error when it crashes? And you still haven't answered my datatype question, which is really the key to the whole thing.

Comment: @ADyson The datatype is Work, the error is "The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'CPATV1Model.Work'. A member of the type, 'Id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name."

Comment: Not really, the rest of the code has nothing related with this part, but the error I think would make sense because I don't have any ID inside the Model, only the EmployeeID which is a GUID, maybe I need to add an ID to match the one in the database. @ADyson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to read the results as a `Work` object:

```
db.Work.SqlQuery("...")
```

But your query will only return a single column.  Presumably the `Work` object has more properties than just a single property called `Total`.

Indeed, from a comment buried in the question above:

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'CPATV1Model.Work'. A member of the type, 'Id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

That's telling you that Entity Framework is trying to populate the model of type `Work`, which has a property called `Id`, but your query returns no such property.

Basically, you're trying to [write a SQL query for an entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql#writing-sql-queries-for-entities).  Instead, this should be [for a non-entity type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql#writing-sql-queries-for-non-entity-types).  Remove the reference to `Work` and specify the return type.

For example:

```
db.SqlQuery<string>("...")
```

This should result in an `IEnumerable<string>`, from which you can read the first record:

```
var query = db.SqlQuery<string>("...");
var total = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I'm not getting the FirstOrDefault() identifier when I type var total = query. , only Equals, GetHashCode, GetType, ToString

Comment: @AAlmeida: Interesting.  What is the runtime type of the “query” variable?  Maybe it’s already a string?  If so, what is its value?

Comment: Had to be var query = db.DataBase.SqlQuery... It worked, thanks.